# What will be the fate of a person who wore amulets and died without knowledge that its a sin?

Tags: jahannam

A person wore amulets thinking it will protect him from evil eye and jinns etc...He has now passed away. Apparently it comes under minor shirk. The person didn't know he was sinning and he died without repenting without even knowing it was a sin.

It is said that all Muslims will eventually go to Jannah ( some after being in hell for some time ). Now my question is- a person who committed minor shirk as stated above- is he a kafir?

Shirk is the sin that Allah will not forgive, but this person still believed in Allah- was he a Muslim or Kafir- Is he doomed for eternal hell ? Or will he still be able to enter Jannah?